# Is it possible to read faster by converting text into shorthand form or symbolic or logoraphic notation?

Tags: language, reading, language-processing, speech, speech-comprehension

People often use speed-writing and stenography to write or type faster, and more words written in a logographic language such as Chinese or Japanese can fit into a standard tweet on Twitter than in a language with a regular alphabet that has no logograms or lexigraphs.

Would it be possible to read a book faster by converting it into a shorthand version of one's native language? If subvocalization creates an upper limit on reading speed, then wouldn't reading a shorthand version of a language reduce both the total amount of text to read and the amount of time spent subvocalizing each word in the text?